# List folder structure in SharePoint Site COllection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have a SharePoint **online** site collection with 17 subsites and a lot of document libraries, folders and sub folders in each subsite.
Is there a powershell script that will list all the subsites, document libraries, folders and sub folders with their url for me?

Comment: Did the script work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this real quick using [PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/), the scripts connect to your site collection and then get's all the libraries and it's folders and store the results in a array. You can then export the array to a CSV using the cmdlt [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.3) or pipe it to Out-GridView.

```
function Get-LibraryAndFolders {

    # get all libraries
    $lists = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq 'DocumentLibrary'}

    # loop through all the libraries
    foreach($list in $lists) {

        # add the library name, type and Url to the array
        $arr.add(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                "Name" = $list.Title
                "Type" = "Library"
                "Url" = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
            }
        )

        # get all the folders in the current list
        $folders = Get-PnPFolder -List $list

        # loop through all the folders
        foreach($folder in $folders) {

            # add the folder name, type and Url to the array
            $arr.add(
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    "Name" = $folder.Name
                    "Type" = "Folder"
                    "Url" = $folder.ServerRelativeUrl
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

# connect to rootsite
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "UrlToYourSite" -UseWebLogin

# create a array to store all objects in
$arr = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()

# get subsites
$subsites = Get-PnPSubWebs

# get library and folders
Get-LibraryAndFolders

# loop through all subsites
foreach($subsite in $subsites) {

    # connect to subsite
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $subsite.Url -UseWebLogin

    # get library and folders
    Get-LibraryAndFolders

    # disconnect from subsite
    Disconnect-PnPOnline
}
```